# Why does my oak tree have clumps of leaves in the winter?

Tags: trees, leaves, oak

It is December in Mississippi. Why do my oak trees have clumps of leaves?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's hard to be certain from just the picture, but that looks like mistletoe: https://tcrcd.net/brochures/pdf/Oak_Mistletoe.pdf.

Comment: Yes, it is mistletoe .

Comment: Ah, I would have never guessed. Thanks. Do I need to get rid of it or is it fine to leave?

Comment: @bill999 according to Wikipedia, mistletoe is a parasite which "extract(s) water and nutrients from the host plant".

Comment: It needs to be removed [with a golden sickle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritual_of_oak_and_mistletoe) :-)

Comment: @bill999 the document linked in this answer answers this, although I believe best practice is for answers not to rely on information contained in external links so these details should probably be included. I think the trees pictured above probably count as trees that are heavily infested that will eventually die if the infected branches aren't removed.

Comment: Well, its definitely mistletoe, and as @Carl mentions, it does need to be removed. But, though it has been a few years since I lived there, I believe in Mississippi, the standard method of removal is with a gun. And you do need to hurry, or you will run out of your opportunity to sell it.